# Does Apportable support to build library binary (.a/.so)?

Tags: apportable

Is it possible to build `.a` or `.so` library files to use with build app body?

If it is not, is it possible to build an Xcode project with multiple sub-projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-projects are supported; they will actually internally build with the build system as static libraries (.a).

However note: that this is slightly different than iOS build procedures in that the build system will automatically treat these libraries as if they had -ObjC -all_load linker flags.

Comment: It should be noted that sub-projects work but sub-sub-projects don't. The latter referring to a subproject that in itself contains one or more subprojects. At least I couldn't get this to work with the error "Warning: Library not found for libsubsub. Try adding this to the 'deps' array ..."