# How to link C/C++ static library built for Android in Apportable?

Tags: linker, apportable

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537856/does-apportable-support-to-build-library-binary-a-so).

If I have some C/C++ static library which is pre-built for Android, can I link it to my application with Apportable build tools? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Or should I re-build any library to use with Apportable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries can be linked, there is an additional flag in the configuration.json that can be modified in the add_params section that will allow for static libraries to be added.

`"libs": [
    "path/to/the/lib.a"
]`

Dynamic libraries can be done in the same manner, however these can definitely cause issues with linkages to our extensions to libc. For example this would prevent that .so from using our optimized malloc implementation, or our virtualized file system accessors etc.

Comment: You mean the issues are limited only to dynamic libraries?

Comment: That is correct per the limitations; static libraries inherit the linker flags since they are compiled into the application's .so (which inherits the rest of the build system flags for specifying the Apportable implementations)